# Did the emulator engine change with the WP7 January 2011 update?

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

Did the emulator itself (XDE) change with the new Windows Phone 7 (January 2011) dev tools update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

What changed is the OS image (built on January 25th, 2011) that now resides in the Windows Phone 7 SDK folder (*C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Emulation\Images*). The emulator engine itself remained intact and you can still boot to the old image (built on September 1st, 2011 - without copy/paste support and performance improvements), in case you saved it.